# How can i set onClicked buttons values into a textfield in reactjs (Calculator)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

recently just learning Reactjs, and I'm trying to build a calculator,

below is the function code from App.js

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <div id="ans" className="answer">Ans = 0</div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="0" className="inputid" id="result"/>
           <hr/> 
           {/* calculator buttons below */}
         
           <button className="opbut">+</button>
           <button className="opbut">-</button>
           <button className="calbut">0</button>
           <button className="calbut">1</button>
           <button className="calbut">2</button>
           <button className="calbut">3</button>
           <button className="opbut">%</button>
           <button className="ansbut">=</button>
           <hr/>
           <div className="appName">A Simple React Calculator - Jayflo</div>
        </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

in the onClick function for each button, i want it so that when clicked, it will display the value of the button clicked and concatenate it with the remaining values in the textfield... but i'm not getting it, after trying all possible solutions i could find online...

And it was due to the upgrade of react from class to function i guess, most are depreciated, i guess.
and i'm a bit new to this, going online, seeing old solutions...

Comment: i suggest removing all comments and provide an https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import './App.css';

export default function App() {

  function handleClick(input) {
    let buttonText = input.target.innerText;
    let inputText = document.getElementById('result').value;
    console.log(inputText + buttonText);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <div id="ans" className="answer">Ans = 0</div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="0" className="inputid" id="result"/>
           <hr/> 
           {/* calculator buttons below */}
         
           <button onClick={handleClick} className="opbut">+</button>
           <button onClick={handleClick} className="opbut">-</button>
           <button onClick={handleClick} className="calbut">0</button>
           <button onClick={handleClick} className="calbut">1</button>
           <button onClick={handleClick} className="calbut">2</button>
           <button onClick={handleClick} className="calbut">3</button>
           <button onClick={handleClick} className="opbut">%</button>
           <button onClick={handleClick} className="ansbut">=</button>
           <hr/>
           <div className="appName">A Simple React Calculator - Jayflo</div>
        </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: but event is depreciated...

Comment: thanks, but tit's not accepting the event....

Comment: also, where does the `concatText` go?

Comment: Elaborate. Is that some error you're getting? If so, can you give me details on that? If not, can you tell me what you mean? Are you saying I can't use "event" because that name's already been taken? If so, to which context are you referring to? The html code, or the javascript function code? You can rename "event" in the calculatorButtonClick function to "input" or whatever you want. As for the html, "event" refers to whatever event you're handling when used in a "on(whatever)" handler, unless I am mistaken, so it ought to work pasted into all of those guys.

Comment: Let me try making it work on my end

Comment: okay, thanks... it reactjs(jsx), not pure javascript

Comment: Sorry, I forgot how different they were. This ought to at least get you the concatenated text you wanted.

Comment: Did you see the edit?

Comment: yes.... untill i added this  `document.getElementById("result").value= inputText + buttonText`